# PHP error during deploying laravel to google cloud platform

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, out-of-memory

I am using Laravel version 5.5.4 and php version 7.2. Currently I am deploying my laravel to the google app engine which I encountered the issue:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 3527409664) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 50

PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 3527409664) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php on line 122
```

I have no issue on hosting locally using `php artisan serve`. This error only occurs when I wanted to deploy to google app engine.

Anyone can help out? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Its an error trying to allocate too much data from yout database objects into a collection.
An amount bigger than the php.ini script is allowed to allocate by the `max_memory` var

Just increase your memory in your `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the memory on the `app.yaml` file and check the `max_memory` var on  `php.ini` if there is memory limit